# TinyMCE: Styles dropdown not getting populate

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

At first sorry for my poor English.
My problem is that i am init tinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : 'testClass',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    plugins: "pagebreak,fullscreen,media,advimage,paste,searchreplace,advlink",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save_button,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,styleselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,|,anchor,|,image,|,cleanup,|,help,|,code",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,|,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap",
});
```

But on page i see Styles dropdown and it is not opening, when i am click on it. Please, help. What i am missed or doing wrong?

Comment: are you using tinymce 4?

Comment: Thariama, 
majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '4.8',
releaseDate : '2012-02-02',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [style_formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3astyle_formats) to add styles to the TinyMCE editor.
See this [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2mdaab/1) for example.

I usually have all my styles defined in an external css file and use content_css to link them to TinyMCE. This is good if you have more style rules or may use the same style rules in multiple places. It keeps the tinyMCE init() script clean. See [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) for more detail. Here is an example [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2mdaab/2) for [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the style plugin to your plugin list.

Comment: Thariama, Sorry, but how can i do this? I am edit init params:
plugins: "pagebreak,fullscreen,media,advimage,paste,searchreplace,advlink,styles",

but dont see effect...